# Is there any way in ubuntu 18.04 to add up/down arrows to all scrollbars (default)?

Tags: 16.04, scrolling, scrollbar

I would like to add up and down arrows to my scrollbars in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

If you are on any page that has a lot of length then it is impossible to grab the scrollbar thumb-wheel and move with any precision.  Often I just barely move it and it moves up multiple pages.

**Example 1 - Long list of email in Mozilla Thunderbird**

This is especially true in Mozilla Thunderbird (for example) where I have thousands of email in my inbox.  Without the arrows you literally cannot move the lines of the email precisely.

Yes, I can click in the list of email and arrow-key down but that is not convenient.

**Example 2 - Long Article In Web Browser**

Also, if you're reading a long article in your browser you will come up against this situation also, but even worse because arrow keys don't really work well on a text article.

**Is This A Styling Thing?**
Can you provide the steps to adding the up/down arrows back to my scrollbars.  I think this was a huge mistake in the UI to remove them.

**What I've Tried?**

I've installed the Tweaks program and tried various themes, but none of the default ones display up/down arrows on scrollbars.  I haven't found a setting in Tweaks that changes it.  If I've missed it, please point it out.

[image: tweaks program]

Comment: Check this out <https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226879>.
Also, a GTK theme that enables the arrows is OneStepBack. But not every application uses GTK, so in some cases there is barely nothing you could do about it.

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks I will try out their suggestion there.  It's really too bad about scrollbars.  They're terribly annoying because they are so narrow also and my mouse misses them often and turns to a resize (window) arrow then I have to slide back to the scrollbar so it'll do the auto-enable thing.  Terrible UI decisions for no known reason.  Why would I want to have to hover over a scrollbar to make it become active?  Just makes no sense.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm firing up VirtualBox and downloading Linux Mint right now to see if it is any different over there.  If it is I will move to Mint or whatever other distro has wide scrollbars and up/down arrows. I switched to Ubuntu about 6 months ago from Win10 and have used it exclusively at home.

Comment: Switching distros in the hope of getting what you want is one way. We've already answered the issue of wider scrollbars here. The up/down arrows are also quite possible. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar and https://askubuntu.com/questions/200938/question-about-gtkscrollbar-class-in-custom-themes/201063#201063.

Comment: @DKBose I used the 2nd answer you posted and solved the problem. Super fantstic. I really didn't want to change distros.  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

to add scrollbar arrows to all ubuntu themes: Create a file in /home/yourusername/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css containing the following:

```
*{
-GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
-GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
-GtkRange-slider-width: 13;
-GtkRange-stepper-size: 13;
}
```

replace yourusername by your user name This applyed the arrows for me for many themes and programs but you will get small arrows.
[image]